# Unable to deploy Angular app to Spring Boot

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, maven, war

I have an Angular app as well as a rest API using Spring Boot that I need to package as a single war file to be deployed on apache tomcat. I have tried:

- building my angular app and pasting the built files into my Spring app
- using the maven war plugin to build the files into a war

Some of the tutorials I have seen seem to show people copying built angular files into Spring static folder and then running spring and it works. This seems strange to me because there are no mappings configured and also does not work. for me.

I think that my best option is to use maven war plugin but my problem is:

- The wars I build inaccessible via the browser when deployed to tomcat
- they result in `The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.` errors
- and I just do not know what to do next

I am hoping that somebody can point me in the right direction here. Thanks in advance.

I have made some changes based on answers and my war file is compiling and found by tomcat, however, the angular app is unable to find any of the other resources and only a blank page is loaded. I get 404 for the styles and other files when looking in dev tools.

I am now using copies of the directories with different names. In my package.json I do this:

```
{
  "name": "task-app-front-end",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxyconfig.json",
  "build": "ng build",
  "test": "ng test",
  "outDir": "../taskappmain\\src\\main\\resources\\public",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e"
}
```

outputting my built files to /public/ directory of my backend application.

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>taskappmain</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>taskappmain</name>
<description>taskAppMain</description>

<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>

                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/public</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources/public</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question, suggesting to use bullet points instead of long paragraphs.

Comment: @YogeshPrajapati I posted an update and was hoping that you could take another look at my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build order should be the following for this to work:

- Build the front-end application (Angular)
- Build the REST application (the Spring Boot app)

You will need to do this because you are going to need the `dist` folder in the angular app, which contains the production code for your front-end.

In your maven build when assembling the war file you will need to do the following:

- First make sure that the prepare-compile and compile phases have run under maven
- In the `Prepare package` phase you will need to copy the files from `front-end/dist/web` into the project `backend` under `target/classes/static/`

The copy action can be done automatically using the Maven Resources Plugin or the Maven AntRun Plugin.

The reason for copying to the `target` directory rather the the `src/main/resources/static` is that the distribution of the Angular app is not 'source' code for the backend.

As to why any file in `static` package is directly available in your WAR, this is because Spring Boot by default has a static resource binding that allows all files in the `static` package from being accessed via the internet. Also see the [Sample project](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) from Spring Boot itself.

For the issue of your backend not working once deployed in Tomcat this could be due to the fact that Tomcat does not know how to start your application. Keep in mind Spring Boot dropped usage of the `web.xml` by default. So to allow the container server (Tomcat) to start Spring Boot you need to add the following to your class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`

```
public class MyRestApp extends SpringBootSerlvetInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
      return builder.sources(MyRestApp.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Gerban I have made some changes to my project based on your answer and I have made some progress. I am now able to deploy my war file to tomcat but the index page is blank. I get 404 for all resources. When I run the project from ide I can access the page without problem.

Comment: Please see above comment